# Compare 2 objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have 2 Objects, let's say:

a:

```
{
  "sale_price": 100,
  "has_pool": yes,
  "rooms": 3
}
```

b:

```
{
  "sale_price": 100,
  "has_pool": no,
  "rooms": 3
}
```

and I would like to compare both, and return the number of fields that match each other ( In this case, it would return 2, because only 2 fields match ).
Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a few ideas. Have you tried out any ideas of your own? Perhaps using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)?

Comment: Is "has_pool", meant to be  true / false..  And are wee assuming a shallow compare?

Comment: Ok, Assuming it's shallow test.  And at the fear of SO police, I'm posting a solution here.  I won't put as a proper solution as it will just get voted down.  Object.keys(a).reduce(function (acc, key) { return acc + (a[key] === b[key]); }, 0)

Answer (score 0):

It's rather naive approach, it will work as long as compared objects doesn't contain objects:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  return Object.keys(a).filter(k => a[k] === b[k]).length
}
```